# How to create a child SQL-Alchemy instance from a parent instance?

Tags: python, class, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two models, `Signal` and `Trade`. My `Trade` object inherits its attributes from `Signal`, as almost all of the attributes are the same, however there are some key functions and attributes which make it different. I'm writing a method on `Signal` called `as_trade()`, I want to create a `Trade` instance from all the data/attributes on the `Signal` instance so I can save it to the database. I was using deepcopy - and this had been working, but in actual fact I don't think this is the correct/best way to do it. Is there a tried/tested way of performing an action like this?

```
class Signal(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'signal'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    class_type = db.Column(db.String())

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'signal',
        'polymorphic_on': class_type,
    }

    # MAIN FIELDS
    type = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def as_trade(self):
       signal_dict = self.__dict__
       for key in ['id', 'user_id', '_sa_instance_state', 'class_type']:
           signal_dict.pop(key)
       trade = Trade(**signal_dict)
       return trade

    ...

class Trade(Signal):
    __tablename__ = 'trade'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('signal.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'trade',
    }
    ....
```

I should add, the issue I'm getting here is that when `as_trade()` is called, it throws a key error. If I call `self.id` in PDB, I get a value (1). However, if I call `self.__dict__` I get only an InstanceState, with no attributes. Hence, it throws a keyError. But sometimes, by calling self_dict and self.**dict** whilst in PDB, I can get the dictionary to actually appear and have values - this is the part I don't understand. Left alone, the program fails here as it throws a keyError given that self.**dict** gives only `InstanceState` object. But poking around in PDB and calling self.**dict** a step ahead in the process allows the for loop to complete because the dictionary appears with all the attributes required...?

```
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x000002E694983B88>
}
```

UPDATE:
The reason its acting funky is because by popping `_sa_instance_state` from the dictionary, the state is acting up. If I leave `_sa_instance_state` in the dictionary object and pass it to Trade(), I get an error `TypeError: '_sa_instance_state' is an invalid keyword argument for Trade`

Comment: I did see that - it was a minefield. I found it very confusing and couldn't quite plot a course of action that suited my usecase well enough. Do you have a tip?

Comment: Does this mean I can simply change the signal.type attribute to `trade` and now magically, that signal instance will be loaded as a trade?

Comment: Yes, but now lets say I have a signal instance, with lots and lots of fields filled out (lots of data). I now want to create a trade instance, with its new methods, but filled out from the signal instance data (which - apart from the functions - is the same.

Comment: Yes I want to preserve signal instance (saved in DB), create new instance of trade, and save this to DB as Trade() object.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful actually. I will use that. I had hoped it would be as simple as signal = Signal(), new_trade=Trade(signal). Alas, it is not. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both the `Signal` class and the `Trade` class share the same database columns and the only way they differ is in the methods defined on the classes, then it makes sense to use a single table inheritance model.

As Flask-SQLAlchemy magically defines table names if you don't define them, you'll need to explicitly set the `__tablename__` attribute of the child class to `None` to signal you intention to use the single table construct.

Then, if the objective is to copy the values of the columns of the `Signal` object over to a new `Trade` object, then you can iterate over the columns of `Signal.__table__` in order to get the values of the column from `Signal` and write them to the new instance of `Trade`.

The loop would look something like this:

```py
signal = db.session.query(Signal).one()
new_trade = Trade()
for col in Signal.__table__.c:
    if col.key not in ("id", "type"):
        setattr(new_trade, col.key, getattr(signal, col.key))
```

Here's a full working example:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///test.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Signal(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "signal"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # MAIN FIELDS
    type = db.Column(db.String(20))
    col1 = db.Column(db.Integer)
    col2 = db.Column(db.Integer)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": "type", "polymorphic_identity": "signal"}


class Trade(Signal):

    __tablename__ = None

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "trade"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(Signal(col1=1, col2=2))
    db.session.commit()
    signal = db.session.query(Signal).one()
    new_trade = Trade()
    for col in Signal.__table__.c:
        if col.key not in ("id", "type"):
            setattr(new_trade, col.key, getattr(signal, col.key))
    db.session.add(new_trade)
    db.session.commit()
    db.session.expire_all()
    trade = db.session.query(Trade).first()
    print(trade.col1, trade.col2)
```